# Logfile-fetcher for some servers

Tags: logs

Whats a free and easy tool to fetch a few logfiles from a handfull of linux-servers and centralize store it on the retrieving server?

I think of a sort of very lightweight splunk or sort of.
But it should be free and without a lot of overweight.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your requirements. Are the servers ssh-able? Do you mean by "centralize store" dropping them in some directory? Then `for S in $SERVERS; for L in $LOGS; do scp $S:$L .; done; done` is very affordable and lightweight.

Comment: Typically, it's done the other way round. The servers configure rsyslog to send logs to a central server, which has configured rsyslog to accepting incoming logs. syslog-ng is an alternative.